# Difference of master-details tables by a table with more data fields

Tags: c#, sql-server

As far as i know when you want to separate related data you have to use master-detail tables.
In a situation I have a **"Statute"** table which store clauses of a statute and their footnotes of each clause.
Table Fields:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  Statute_ID | Statute_Text | CanEdit | CanDelete | FootNote_Sort | ParentClause | Parent_Sort + 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
You can see that all data (Clauses and thier Notes) Stores in a table.
 In a C# project the project manager says that this will be better than master-details tables but i believe that separating Notes form Clauses would be better. 


Could anyone told me that which scenario will be better? and what is the benefit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master detail tables are used where you have **one to many** relationship between the data.

For Example, In business applications, usually the transactions have a master record which holds the date and serial number of the transaction while it has a detail record which can hold a number of entries with each detail having a reference to the master(usually made via Foreign Key relation between master table and detail table in SQL).

In your case you have a single entry about the statue, i.e. Clauses and their Notes will be same for a single statue so you won't be needing a master detail relation

Comment: Although just a few clauses needs to have their notes but if we have a few notes for a clause, does it mean one to many relation?

Comment: yes. then you assign an ID to your clause and make a one to many relationship with your childs